# Grunt synchronous task

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I can't wrap my head around a basic grunt loop running tasks sequentially, and I can't figure it out. Basically I am setting a grunt.option in a loop, and the following tasks use the option in their config. The problem is that grunt seems to run things entirely out of order, so the "option" is set to the last value in the loop, before the following task runs:

```
var skins = ['daylight','twilight'];
grunt.registerTask('skins', function(){
  grunt.util.recurse(skins, function(val){
    grunt.option('skin', val); // This runs twice first
    grunt.task.run(['replace:styles','sass:dist']); // ... before this
  })
});
```

Basically the option gets set to the last array val before the first task runs. Any tips appreciated to get this running sequentially ...

Comment: Thanks to @drorb for pointing out why this is not working. Due to my somewhat lack of experience with grunt/node, I ended up solving this with a simple a simple bash script in terminal, which simply processes a few grunt tasks, in order:
```alias skins='grunt sassy --skin=daylight && grunt sassy --skin=twilight'```

Answer (score 1):

`grunt.task.run` enqueues the task(s) to run immediately after the current task completes. This means that `'replace:styles'` and `'sass:dist'` will run after the `'skins'` task completes and at this stage the `'skin'` option is set to the last value in the list.